# what does $this->getUrl('fastorder/index/saveOrder') refers to

Tags: magento-1.9

i am new to magento and i didn't understand purely about the structure of magento

what problems me is this

```
$this->getUrl('fastorder/index/saveOrder')
```

i need to find where this line refers to used in the following code

```
 <form id="fastorder-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('fastorder/index/saveOrder')?>" method="post">
```

because my form post values to this location and i need to do few modifications.

I appreciate the help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$this->getUrl('fastorder/index/saveOrder')** is create a url.
According to magento,this give url which

**Like**: `YourSiteUrl/FronteNameOFAThridPartetensin/index/savOrder`
Then

## fastorder: it identifier of a module router

Goto **app/code/(community or local)/TheModuleNameSpace/MouleName/etc/** and open **config.xml**

then here you find

```
  <routers>
            <fastorder><!-- this call in getUrl (fastorder),it call as router name --> 
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>TheModuleNameSpace_MouleName</module>
                    <frontName>fastorder</frontName><!-- frontend name -->
                </args>
            </fastorder>
        </routers>
```

May be `router name  and frontend name` it depend on development. Actually fronted name show when url route

**controller:** `IndexController.php`

**Action Name:**  `saveOrderAction()`

Comment: thats exactly what i am looking for ... 
and i found it ... thanks